# Figures tangent to other figures

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all values of $d$ where the graph of the polynomial $x^2-2014x+d$ is tangent to the graph of $x^2+2014x+y^2+2014y=-4056196$.

$4056196=2014^2=(2*1007)^2=4(1007)^2$

$(x+1007)^2 +(y+1007)^2=-4(1007)^2 +2(1007^2)=-2(1007)^2$

It seems that I have a circle with a negative radius. Is the problem stated correctly? Suppose I have a circle, how will I know when and how often a parabola is tangent to it?

Answer (score 0):

Graph any curve and its tangent line at some point on the curve (such as $e^x$ and $1+x$, the tangent line at $x=0$), then those two curves intersect and are tangent at that point of intersection.

In general, they are tangent if their tangent curves (or "planes" in general) point in the same direction (or have same "normals" or whatever). So you would need to check whether $$Df=Dg$$ the derivatives at the point of intersection are equal.